# Erro ao tentar usar usar MediaPlayer

Tags: android

tentei elaborar um Botão que quando pressionado execute um som, mas sei como importar esse som e nao sei como localizar a pasta Raw, quando tento usar essa linha:

```
mpSongButtons = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.);
```

Da erro, ou seja, essa Raw nao existe, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ExecutaSomExemplo {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Conecta o button do xml
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        //Método de ação do clique
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      //Cria o objeto MediaPlayer que irá receber o arquivo de som
                      MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.nomedoarquivo);

                       //Toca a música
                       mPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
        );
    } 
}
```

---

No seu caso específico em que você está usando o `Eclipse` a pasta `raw` não vem criada como padrão, você tem que criá-la: clique com o botão direito sobre a pasta res, selecione `Novo...` depois `Pasta` e digite o nome da pasta, como na imagem:

[image: nova pasta]

Então, você pode criar novos arquivos lá, seja arrastando-e-soltando o arquivo dentro dela, ou clique novamente com o botão direito na pasta raw e selecione `Novo...` e depois `Arquivo`.

Comment: mas nao consigo usar esse metodo pois nao existe o endereço R.raw.nomedoarquivo, da erro quando tento usar "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Certifique se o arquivo é do tipo `.mp3` exemplo: nomedoarquivo.mp3, também certifique que o arquivo está no diretório `res/raw` do seu projeto. Caso tudo esteja certo dê um `Clean/Build` e tente rodar novamente.

Comment: Mas nao existe a pasta Raw, essa é minha duvida, nao existe essa pasta no meu projeto, estou usando a ultima versao do ADT Plugin

Comment: Qual IDE você está usando @Jeiferson? Eclipse, Netbeans, Android Studio?

Comment: IDE Eclipse @iTSangar

Comment: Adicionei uma breve solução pro seu caso na resposta que eu eu criei @Jeiferson, caso precise de algo mais é só falar =)

Comment: Vlw cara, era isso...